# VLC Media Client IPv6 Multicasting Issues

Tags: streaming, vlc, ipv6, multicast

I am streaming using VLC over an IPv6 network. The server side is working fine however for the client, it doesn't send any IPv6 Multicast Listener Reports when I open the stream.

I have checked on Wireshark and there are no Multicast Listener Reports being sent for the multicast address.
Any suggestions?

I am using VLC 3.0.18 Vetinari on Rocky 8.7.

I've tried on both CLI and GUI - here's the CLI output showing the addressing seems to be ok:

```
[00007f678401ac30] main input debug: `rtp://[ff0a::a]:1234' gives access `rtp' demux `any' path `[ff0a::a]:1234'
[00007f679000c4e0] main input source debug: creating demux: access='rtp' demux='any' location='[ff0a::a]:1234' file='(null)'
[00007f679000ec50] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "rtp": 20 candidates
[00007f679000ec50] main demux debug: net: opening ff0a::a datagram port 1234
[00007f679000ec50] main demux debug: using access_demux module "rtp"
```

Thanks in advance.

Jeff

Comment: IPv6 multicast addressing is complex, with flags and scopes, The scope in your address is an unused, unassigned scope, and you really should not use it. Also, you probably want to stay away from any `::a` multicast address as that is normally for EIGRP Routers when your flags indicate a well-known multicast address as your flags indicate. You should probably use something in the `ff12::/24` range that is a transient, link-local or in the `ff15::/24` range that is a transient, site-local multicast address. Try using something like `ff12::1234`.

Comment: It's a problem with VLC not my addresses (it's all within a private test network). With VLC 2.2.8 it works fine, with Multicast Listener Reports coming from the VLC client.

Comment: You should still pay attention to the flags and scopes an not misuse the IPv6 multicast addressing. It is very flexible, but complex. If you define your own multicast addresses, you need to set the Transient flag, and you should only use the correct scope. Simply making things up like this can create hard to troubleshoot problems later, even if it works today. Remember that IPv6, itself, makes heavy use of multicast.

Comment: Ok sure, thanks for the advice Ron. As per your suggestion, I am now using ff15::1234 which works fine for my VLC server and PIM router, but the current VLC doesn't seem to send any multicast listener reports.